# DOMPDF change the html elements places

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, dompdf

I am working with laravael,I have an HTML view that has CSS integrated. I want to convert into a PDF. If I open the view (it doesn't mather if I open it via my Documents or by a link in my app) it works fine, everything looks ok. But if I get that file and generate a PDF with dompdf, when I open it the css for the background and the images are in their places but the texts change places and have another size.

Here is how I convert it to a PDF

```
    $file = file_get_contents("../resources/views/panel/historial/pdfs/otros.html");

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->loadHtml($file);
    //$dompdf->load_html_file($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("otros.pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));

    return $dompdf;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esBl9.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not working in that way to except then the DOMPDF-Renderer has not the full CSS functionality.

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility

Here is a list of elements that are supported. So in your case i would suggest that you render a new template and make it with a different style for your PDF.

Another good solution is **wkhtmltopdf** which has a better support but is a command line tool which you have to call over php or if you don't need PHP then run it directly from your command line.

https://wkhtmltopdf.org/